# Labeling line with cumulative distance

Tags: labeling, line, distance

[image: Example]

Regarding one line, lets think on a road, how can you label that line with cumulative distance, starting from first vertex?

QGIS v3.26.2

Comment: Welcome to gis stackexchange! What software are you using? And what version?

Comment: @julsbreakdown QGIS 3.26.2

Answer (score 2):

Run `points along line`, creating a point e.g. every kilometer, then label those points with their attribute indicating how far down the line they are.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That should work. In 'points along line' It's possible to force last vertex? And reverse first and last vertex (so count distance from last to first vertex)?

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. Convert your line to line segments (using https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines)
2. Create and calculate the length of the resulting line `(length = $length)`
3. Create a new column ie: cumulation
4. Populate using an expression

```
    if($id = 1, attribute($currentfeature, 'length'), 
    attribute($currentfeature, 'length') + 
    attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id-1), 'cumulation'))
```

5. Use the label on the result and add it at the end of line
   [image]

ie [image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this way I get labels per vertex cut segment, that is, segments with different sizes. I need labels always at the same distance, for example 1km, whose label value is the accumulated lenght from the initial vertex.